# display a subset of regions using a shapefile in R

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I have a shapefile of the UK: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/Docs/Boundaries/Local_authority_district_(GB)_2014_Boundaries_(Generalised_Clipped).zip

I've read the shapefile into a variable, UK

```
>UK <- readOGR(dsn = "....."
>England <- UK
```

I'd like to only display English Local Authority regions. They are specified in the LAD_DEC_2014_GB_BGC.dbf where LAD14CD starts with "E"

```
>UK@data

      LAD14CD                      LAD14NM                 LAD14NMW

0   E06000001                   Hartlepool                     <NA>
1   E06000002                Middlesbrough                     <NA>
2   E06000003         Redcar and Cleveland                     <NA>
371 W06000015                      Cardiff                 Caerdydd

>#filter UK@data and replace England@data with only English regions
>England@data <- UK@data$LAD14CD[c(grep("^E", UK$LAD14CD))]

>plot(England)
```

But the grep command appears to change the shapefile into a factor, meaning the plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The problem is plot(UK) works fine, but I can't seem to filter the regions down

Comment: Maybe `UK@data$LAD14CD[substr(UK$LAD14CD,1) == "E"]`?

Comment: thanks, that gets the IDs I need, but I need to subset the UK@Data using these IDs. I can do this with: England@data[England$LAD14CD %in% UK@data$LAD14CD[substr(UK$LAD14CD,1,1) == "E"],] but how do I overwrite England@data with this new subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this command:

```
England <- UK@data$LAD14CD[c(grep("^E", UK$LAD14CD))]
```

...you are subsetting just one column from the data slot, not the whole shapefile  and assigning that to `England`.

This ought to do the job:

```
England <- UK[grep("^E", UK@data$LAD14CD),]
```

Note, you need the trailing comma in there! Also you don't need to wrap the grep statement in `c()`, but that doesn't hurt it's just unnecessary.

Comment: it errors out:
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: The following gets the correct rows: UK@data[UK$LAD14CD %in% UK$LAD14CD[c(grep("^E", UK$LAD14CD))],]  but there must be a neater way? Your code still gives the same error as before :(

Comment: Your link doesn't lead immediately to a download, so it's pretty hard to test. If you post the `head` of `UK@data` it would be easier to help you

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated the link. The head command is almost identical to the data posted above

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `dplyr` and `grepl` instead to make things simpler:

```
library('rgdal')
library('dplyr')

UK <- readOGR(dsn="LAD_DEC_2014_GB_BGC.shp", layer="LAD_DEC_2014_GB_BGC") %>%
  subset(grepl("^E", LAD14CD))
plot(UK)
```